# Exposing local WCF service through Azure Appfabric Relay Service

Tags: azure, appfabric, azure-appfabric

I've been following the Pluralsight demo from [this new course](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=azure-sb), in the section "Demo: Configure an Existing Service to use the Relay Service".

All is well until I come to the point where I expect to see the services listed in appfabric at `https://MyURL.servicebus.windows.net/`

Nothing shows up.

I've gone through everything a number of times, checking and rechecking my settings.

My service is hosted in IIS, it's running, the web.config has it set to listen to the above URL, I've configured Auto-start, and it refreshed when I changed the setting, so it *should* be listening, but yet no services show up.

I had [this net.pipe error](http://blogs.digitaldeposit.net/saravana/post/2011/06/23/AppFabric-Service-Bus-netpipe-needs-to-be-specified-error.aspx), and I've followed the fix for that so that no errors show up in the event log.

Anything else I could be missing or that I could check?

How is my hosted service "listening" and how does it "publish" its service data onto the service bus? is there something I can sniff to see how/why it is failing?

I am aware the network setup is important and I need specific ports need to be open etc. Our IT guys assure me the correct ports are open and the machine should be able to get through them.

I have also enabled auto-start on the Site and the service.

**Update**
I have managed to self-host the service programatically, which publishes the service into the Azure service bus feed and can call the service using the service bus endpoint across the web - this proves the network ports are all open, but I still want to have it hosted in IIS.

Here is my web.config with secure personal details removed (apologies, it's a biggie!)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpRelayBinding>
        <binding name="anonymous">
          <security relayClientAuthenticationType="None" />
        </binding>
      </webHttpRelayBinding>
      <netTcpRelayBinding>
        <binding name="Hybrid">
          <security relayClientAuthenticationType="None" />
        </binding>
      </netTcpRelayBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyBehaviour">
          <serviceRegistrySettings discoveryMode="Public" displayName="My Service" />
          <transportClientEndpointBehavior credentialType="SharedSecret">
            <clientCredentials>
              <sharedSecret issuerName="Listener" issuerSecret="MYSECRET"></sharedSecret>
            </clientCredentials>
          </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="MyBehaviourRest">
          <serviceRegistrySettings discoveryMode="Public" displayName="My Rest Service" />
          <transportClientEndpointBehavior credentialType="SharedSecret">
            <clientCredentials>
              <sharedSecret issuerName="Listener" issuerSecret="MYSECRET"></sharedSecret>
            </clientCredentials>
          </transportClientEndpointBehavior>
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="My.NameSpace.IContract"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="Rest" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="My.NameSpace.IContract"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="https://MYURL.servicebus.windows.net/MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehaviour" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="My.NameSpace.IContract"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="sb://MYURL.servicebus.windows.net/MyServiceNet" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehaviour" binding="netTcpRelayBinding" contract="My.NameSpace.IContract"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="https://MYURL.servicebus.windows.net/MyServiceRest" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehaviourRest" binding="webHttpRelayBinding" bindingConfiguration="anonymous" contract="My.NameSpace.IContract"></endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <extensions>
      <!-- In this extension section we are introducing all known service bus extensions. User can remove the ones they don't need. -->
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="connectionStatusBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ConnectionStatusElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="transportClientEndpointBehavior" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TransportClientEndpointBehaviorElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="serviceRegistrySettings" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.ServiceRegistrySettingsElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </behaviorExtensions>
      <bindingElementExtensions>
        <add name="netMessagingTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingTransportExtensionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="tcpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.TcpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="httpRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="httpsRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.HttpsRelayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="onewayRelayTransport" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.RelayedOnewayTransportElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </bindingElementExtensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        <add name="basicHttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.BasicHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="webHttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WebHttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="ws2007HttpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.WS2007HttpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netTcpRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetTcpRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netOnewayRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetOnewayRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netEventRelayBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Configuration.NetEventRelayBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <add name="netMessagingBinding" type="Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Configuration.NetMessagingBindingCollectionElement, Microsoft.ServiceBus, Version=1.6.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </bindingExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Here is one blog entry which can help you:- http://www.infosysblogs.com/cloud/2011/06/basic_steps_to_expose_the_on-p.html The manual settings of IIS described in Appendix A is what you might be looking for. [update]
There is one more blog of Wade Wagner on same issue:- http://www.wadewegner.com/2010/05/host-wcf-services-in-iis-with-service-bus-endpoints/

Comment: Your service is listening to https://MyURL.servicebus.windows.net/[whatever you list as the service]. How is your service failing? Is there an exception being thrown on the server side? What does your code look like to set up your ServiceHost?